# jBPM Business Central rest api 401 unauthorized

Tags: jbpm

I am getting `401 Unauthorized response` for the api call http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/spaces. In response i get a html page with username/password.

I followed the process defined in [jbpm7.28.0.Final documentation page.](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.28.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#knowledge-store-rest-api-con_business-processes) If i use browser to request the endpoint, I am prompted with username/password but that is not accepted.

After I created the user with rest-all role, i have checked the user is added successfully. The role and user are added to application-roles and application-users.properties files.

I have tried with postman and chrome as rest clients. Looks like there is an issue on the server side. I don't see any logs on server console. Business central works properly at http://localhost:8080/business-central/

*jBPM build is:* 7.28.0.Final 
Laptop with *Windows 10 Pro* 
Standard installation of jBPM running on H2 database as of now.

Should I enable anything else on the server before invoking rest endpoints for business central?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When tried with user krisv/krisv, it works fine.

Alternatively, I created a user using admin login from Business Central. It also works fine.